# How do you highlight a missing city on a Political Immunity form?

Tags: papers-please

I noticed that sometimes a request for political immunity does not allow the person access to Arstotzka, but I couldn't work out how to highlight that discrepancy. Is there any way to do that or do you just have to deny the passport without giving a reason?

Comment: do you have a screenshot of this?

Comment: No sorry, it was a normal asylum request but Arstotzka was not in the list of regions at the bottom. I approved the passport and got a citation saying something like "incorrect region in asylum request".

Comment: Have you tried connecting the Asylum request's regions with the rule about asylum requests? That's the way it works for diplomats, after all.

Comment: It was actually a political immunity document, not an asylum request. I'll close this until I can get a good example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you go to the page about the diplomat documents in your rulebook, on the right there is a gray box stating that Arstotzka must be included in the stated countries. To highlight the discrepancy of missing Arstotzka, just connect the list of the countries on the document to this gray box in the rulebook.